# Configuring Network PPPOE Connection using cmd.exe

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, pppoe

Is there a way to configure PPOE (WAN) connection using command line tool only?

I need this information for purpouse of creating .bat (.ps if needed) file that would allow auto-configuration of connections on workstations.

Tried to search, but couldn't find any commands that would be capable of setting up connection and then modifying it (setting user name and password - or setting up in one go).

Comment: Still looking and farest i got would be netsh command. Not sure if its possible to dump PPOE (WAN) interface options to back them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To Connect to internet via CMD.EXE, copy and past the Broadband Connection name; follow these steps.

   > rasdial Broadband_Connection PPPoe_Username PPPoE_Password
   >   e.g. `rasdial Broadband_Connection username password`
2. To disconnect

   > rasdial Broadband_Connection /disconnect